# A formidable question in an analysis textbook

Tags: calculus

[image]

So, I found this question in a calculus textbook. Of course, this can be computed by hand. However, I would like to know if they really mean to derivate this or if there is a hidden trick we can use to derivate this easily

Comment: Maybe the author had a bad day...

Comment: Maybe the author was thinking, "instead of having to come up with fifty exercises in differentiation for this chapter, I could just write **one**...."

Comment: Yes the author of this textbook demonstrates by that he's a great teacher.

Comment: Get a better book asap.